# Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently creating a Bluetooth chat application with Xcode 8 that allows two devices to connect to each other via Bluetooth and send and receive messages to one another. Below is the code for this.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    let messageUUID = CBUUID(string: "053D6600-821E-46A7-AC25-43A81D948E8B")
    let inputUUID = CBUUID(string: "49A79D26-5323-4374-81EA-29B099AF85C8")
    let otherUUID = CBUUID(string: "053D6600-821E-46A7-AC25-43A81D948E87")
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!
    var characteritic: CBMutableCharacteristic!
    var getDataPeripheralCharacteristic: CBMutableCharacteristic!
    var service: CBMutableService!
    var outputData:String = ""
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var connectingPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    var centralWriteCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic!

    @IBOutlet weak var inputLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func centralMode(sender: AnyObject) {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        peripheralManager = nil
    }

    @IBAction func peripheralMode(sender: AnyObject) {
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        centralManager = nil
    }


    func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAddService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
        peripheral.stopAdvertising()
        let identifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
        let manufacturerData = identifier.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        let dataToBeAdvertised:[String: Any] = [
            CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : "Sample peripheral",
            CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey : manufacturerData as Any,
            CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : [messageUUID, inputUUID],
            ]

        peripheralManager.startAdvertising(dataToBeAdvertised)
    }


    @IBAction func sendData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (peripheralManager != nil) {
            let passed = peripheralManager.updateValue(inputLabel.text!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, for: characteritic!, onSubscribedCentrals: nil)
            if passed == false {
                print("error couldn't send data")
            }
        }
        if (centralManager != nil) {
            if (connectingPeripheral != nil) {
                connectingPeripheral?.writeValue(inputLabel.text!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, for: centralWriteCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            }
        }
    }


    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if (peripheral.state == .poweredOn) {
            characteritic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: messageUUID, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.notify, value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readable)
            getDataPeripheralCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: inputUUID, properties:
                CBCharacteristicProperties.write, value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.writeable)
            service = CBMutableService(type: otherUUID, primary: true)
            service.characteristics = [characteritic!, getDataPeripheralCharacteristic!]
            peripheralManager!.add(service)
        }
    }


    func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWriteRequests requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
        for request in requests {
            if (request.characteristic.uuid.uuidString == inputUUID.uuidString) {
                outputData = String(data: request.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                outputLabel.text = outputData
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveReadRequest request: CBATTRequest) {
    }




    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
            //search for peripheral device
        }
    }


    //when peripheral is discovered, this method is called

    private func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        self.centralManager.stopScan();
        self.connectingPeripheral = peripheral;
        peripheral.delegate = self;
        centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }

    //if connection request from central is succesfull, this method is called
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self;
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    //if central discovers services, this method is called
    private func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
        for service: CBService in peripheral.services! {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }

    private func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
        if (service.uuid.uuidString == otherUUID.uuidString) {
            guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
                return
            }
            for characteristic in characteristics {
                if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == messageUUID.uuidString {
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                } else if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == inputUUID.uuidString {
                    centralWriteCharacteristic = characteristic
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error reading characteristics");
        }
        if (characteristic.uuid == messageUUID) {
            outputData = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            print(outputData)
            outputLabel.text = outputData
        }
    }


}
```

The Thread 1 signal SIGABRT error is produced when I click either central mode or peripheral mode but not when I click send data. I have done some research online and the general solution to this error is to check the connections for the buttons and make sure there is only one connection and it is the correct one. I have done this but it still has not fixed the error. Below are images of the connections for these buttons.

[central mode button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Oub.png)

[peripheral mode button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6DFo.png)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: `unrecognized selector` Show the WHOLE Error message for that. It has plenty of informations! It's a well known issue and would greatly help us to debug.

Comment: Stack trace: 2017-08-01 09:00:51.274 BluetoothChat3[953:11683] -[BluetoothChat3.ViewController peripheralMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ae1d03b80
2017-08-01 09:00:51.278 BluetoothChat3[953:11683] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BluetoothChat3.ViewController peripheralMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9ae1d03b80'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Edit your question and put the stack trace there, instead of comments. Try to disconnect and re-connect the actions for your buttons.

Comment: one thing centralManager: CBCentralManager!. It should not be made nil if it is implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: Yes, this worked thank you very much.

Comment: What do you suggest I change about my code then? Should I delete the code which sets it as nil?

Comment: The code is a Swift2/Swift3 jumble. Update your code to the proper Swift 3 syntax. The signatures for `IBAction`s and delegate methods have changed. Look up the methods in the documentation.

Comment: I am very new to programming with swift and my code has been taken from an app written in swift 2 which I have tweaked slightly to remove errors which explains it having elements of swift 3 as well. Could you suggest how to edit my code to make it applicable for swift 3? I would be extremely grateful as I am very unsure on how to go about it

Comment: All IBActions and delegate methods start with an underscore in Swift 3 (like `sendData(_`). A simple way to get the actual signature is to comment out an entire method, retype the first characters and use code completion. Then copy the code of the body into the proper method. Anyway if you want to program applications you have to get used to read the documentation.